# Word "Appendix" in ToC with memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, appendices

There are a lot of Q'n'As around this topic but I could find the answer neither here nor in the memoir manual. Help me please.

I'd like to modify the ToC in such a way, that the word "Appendix" appears in the beginning of each appendix line (now starting with A, B etc). I've tried the appendix package but I get 'option clash' error with `\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use:

```
\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{Appendix\space}
```

And the MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{Appendix\space}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\appendix

\chapter{An Appendix}

\end{document}
```